# DataGrid - Add row that isn't part of the data (for "directory navigation")

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that works as a sort of directory (some items are folders and can be navigated by double clicking on them). I currently have a button with full functionality of going back up a folder level, but I would like to transfer this functionality to a row in the `DataGrid`, as a pseudo-folder labelled `..` an example of which is shown in the image below:

[image]

My main question is, how can I add a new row to the top of the DataGrid, where the row is not part of the data used as `ItemSource` for the `Datagrid`? And if possible, how can I ensure it stays at the top even after sorting.

Comment: Look into `CompositeCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mostly solve this issue by adding a new item to the `Datagrid` with the name `..` . This item was a new class, to which I passed the functionality of the button I made previously. I have an Enum to check the type of file clicked inside the `Datagrid` and binded the appropriate function to each type. The only issue I have left is to ensure this `..` folder stays at the top of the `DataGrid`.